# Libcamera does not work on the latest OS

Tags: pi-3, camera, rpi-update, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I bought the new HD RPi camera and want to connect it to my RPi 3. I checked on the Rpi website that raspistill is being replaced by libcamera, so I updated the OS to the most recent build (Bullseye) and installed libcamera-apps via apt-get.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ neofetch --off
pi@raspberrypi
--------------
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) aarch64
Host: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
Kernel: 5.10.63-v8+
Uptime: 1 min
Packages: 1397 (dpkg)
Shell: bash 5.1.4
Resolution: 1920x1080
WM: Weston WM
Theme: Adwaita [GTK3]
Icons: Adwaita [GTK3]
Terminal: /dev/pts/0
CPU: BCM2835 (4) @ 1.200GHz
Memory: 259MiB / 909MiB
```

When I run the *libcamera-hello* I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ libcamera-hello
[0:01:57.570234297] [1429]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:294 libcamera v0.0.0
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***
```

The official website mentioned that:

```
When running a Raspberry Pi OS based on Bullseye or later, the 5 basic libcamera-apps are already installed. In this case, official Raspberry Pi cameras will also be detected and enabled automatically.
```

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: "I would appreciate any suggestions!" 1. Don't **EVER** use `rpi-update`. 2. If you want to test pre-release OS check the limitations - specifically camera doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know where I could get a working Bullseye image that has libcamera preinstalled?

Comment: You will have to wait until it is released. Libcamera is in Buster.

Comment: I have the same issue on buster with the official high quality camera and libcamera. I can only live preview with `qv4l2`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my pi3, and the cameraV2.
I finally solved it.
Here is one hint from the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html):

> Pi 3 and older devices may not by default be using the correct display
> driver. Refer to the /boot/config.txt file and ensure that either
> dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d or dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d is currently active.
> Please reboot if you needed to change this.

What it doesn't say is to ensure the "dtoverlay" statement is in the [all] section, not the [pi4] section. Since you have a pi3, I think this might apply to you too. I did not have to upgrade beyond buster.